# How to inject or know if my wireless card is injectable

Tags: wireless, security

what ways or methods exist to know if a wireless card is injectable or can be injected (Packet injection). Answers should not include recommending me to use another OS that is not the official Ubuntu or Ubuntu direct derivatives (Like Kubuntu, Lubuntu or Xubuntu).

Comment: Did you really tried to say *wireless card* or did you tried to say *wireless router*?

Comment: Wireless card. For wireless router I would go with the openwrt project

Comment: I never hear that a wireless card could be injectable. How do you know about that? Or, in what document have you read something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aireplay-ng` command [can do this for you](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=injection_test#basic_test). Once your card is in [monitor mode](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng), just run:

```
sudo aireplay-ng -9 <your_interface>
```

Note that your card will need to support monitor mode (you can check this with [`iw list`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829977/how-to-check-if-you-cards-supports-monitor-mode)), and you will need the `aircrack-ng` package installed.