# How to check if you cards supports monitor mode

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

How can I check if my wireless card supports monitor mode, e.g. for use with `aircrack-ng`?

I know there is a command that shows something like wifi adapters attributes or something, but I can't remember.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `iw` command to get a full list of all capabilities of a physical wireless card:

```
$ iw list
Wiphy phy0
    [...]
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    [...]
```

The output of `iw list` is really long and detailed, therefore I only showed the relevant section. You see `monitor` is listed as supported interface mode for my example card.

Comment: @ByteCommander - Or just `iw list | grep monitor`

Comment: @AndroidDev There might be more occurrences of the word "monitor" though. I'd prefer manual examination of the output here.

Comment: @byte I can't see AP in iw list for MT7601 chipset, means. Hardware does not support ? or drivers is not comparable in Linux  ?

Comment: @Nullpointer Probably needs a special driver. Have a look if https://askubuntu.com/q/1205254/367990 helps and search online for your model name and "Linux". If you can't find a working solution, best ask a new question on the site.